# Making two child components into same height in a parent component

Tags: reactjs, css

I have a component which renders two child component,  and I want two components to be in same height considering following conditions  1. when the screen is in normal size 2. when I am resizing the screen   What would be the best strategy to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by `normal size`? Rather then that I would suggest using [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) model.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a bit of `JQuery` to achieve that. Check for the highest child and apply the value to the other one.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            $(".child1").height("auto");
            $(".child2").height("auto");
            var height = Math.max($(".child1").outerHeight(), $(".child2").outerHeight());
            $(".child1").height(height);
            $(".child2").height(height);
        }).resize();
    });
```

```css
.child1 {background-color:red; float:left; width:50%;}
.child2 {background-color:blue; float:left; width:50%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div class="child1">
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  </div>
</div>
```